# Wrong shell in terminal emulators

Tags: shell, fedora

I have a weird problem with my choosen shell (zsh) on my fedora desktop. When I open a terminal emulator the shell is bash but in my `/etc/passwd` is the following:

```bash
[frank@fedora ~]$ grep frank /etc/passwd
frank:x:1000:1000:Frank:/home/frank:/usr/bin/zsh
[frank@fedora ~]$ whoami
frank
```

This happens in every installed terminal emulator (gnome-terminal, alacritty, konsole) and there are no shell specific settings in the terminal emulator set.
An other user on the same computer doesn't have this problem. So I assume it's an user specific setting.

I tried to rename `~/.profile` and even `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bashrc` but with no success.

This happens to me only locally. When I ssh into the machine my shell is zsh as it should.

Comment: Have you just changed your shell? You may need to log out (completely) and back in again for `gnome-terminal` to notice

Comment: No, unfortunately not I rebootet often, but I was in fact really dumb. I'll answer my own question shortly.

Comment: Do you set a variable `SHELL` somewhere?

Comment: Yes :( see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I didn't log out after deleting `~/profile`. So the `SHELL` variable was still set.
What happened was in `~/.profile` were the following:

```bash
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

and in `~/.bashrc` `/etc/bashrc` was sourced and there is an `export SHELL=/usr/bin/bash`
After deleting the above in `.profile` everthing works fine.
Sorry for the dumb question :/